# Printing of variable bound to another print

Tags: c

I am printing four variables at the end of my program.

```
    int n = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < count; n++)
        printf("sorted array:%d\n ", array[n]);

        int last = array[0];
        int unique = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (array[i] != last) {
                last = array[i];
                unique++;
            }
        }

        char *start;
        int c;
        int value;
        int step;

        c = 0;
        start = line;
        while (sscanf(start, "%d%n", array + c, &step) == 1) {
            start += step;
            c += 1;
        }

        value = 1;
        int j;
        for (j = 1; j < c; ++j) {
            value += (array[j] - array[j - 1]) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        printf("integers: %d ", count);

    }

    /* Close the file */
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The only way that I can print the correct value of the variable `unique` is if I keep the `printf("sorted array:%d\n", array[n]);`. However, I used that `printf` statement for testing purposes only and do not want that to print when my program executes.

If I remove `for(n = 0; n < count; n++)` and `printf("sorted array:%d\n", array[n]);`, the value for `unique` is always one which is incorrect.

I have never seen anything like this before. Any suggestions as to why the `printf` of one variable seems to be bound to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep your `for` loop, then at the end of it, we have `n = count`. If you remove it, you have `n = 0`. This then changes your second `for` loop, as `i` doesn't take the same values.

Comment: Wow..thank you. I appreciate it. I feel a bit dumb. (: Thank you again. I will accept your answer when the time is up.

Comment: Dumb errors are often very hard to spot by yourself, but easy for others. [Get a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), he may save you some precious time :-)

Comment: Haha! I have one actually...I will have to use it. Thank you again and for the laugh! (: